# How to convert float to int for date in php using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

`$row['A']` contains `13/03/2019`

```
PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP(trim($row['A']));
```

return float value

But `date()` function in `PHP` takes `int`

```
date('Y-m-d',PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP(trim($row['A'])));
```

so it return 0

```
var_dump(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP(trim($row['A'])));exit();
```

showing result :`float(2087015296)`

```
print_r(intval(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP(trim($row['A']))));exit();
```

showing result: `2087015296`

```
print_r(date('Y-m-d',2087015296));exit();
```

showing result `2036-02-19`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `$row['A']` data to php acceptable date format,

After that pass it directly to `date()` function to change it's format in your desired way

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(trim(str_replace('/','-',$row['A']))));
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/beUIG